Taking a complete screenshot in Qt. How?
I am trying to take a screenshot in Qt. I used the sample screenshot program that is included. (It is here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html, code is here: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/desktop/screenshot?h=6.7)
But it is only taking a screenshot of the Qt app along with the desktop background, i.e. the only window included is of the Qt app. It is not taking a screenshot of what is actually on screen. How do I remedy this?
For clarification, the first image following this is the desired screenshot which worked once, and only once (the first time building the sample screenshot program, for some reason), and every other time is the screenshot result which only includes the Qt app window:
Desired screenshot:

Limited screenshot:

I tried to do this as well using the native Mac OS API, and that had the same result.
I set the permissions to permit these programs to screen record in Mac OS system preferences.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Sorry but your question is unclear: as long as you're properly using grabWindow(0), it should capture the whole screen ("the app and the desktop background" is a confusing description). The fact that you get the same even using macOS API (which one?) is even more confusing. Can you please provide an image of what you get and the image you expect instead? Also, include a proper [mre].

I clarified more in my edit to the post. The issue that I am having is that grabWindow(0) is not doing that, at least on my machine. The only solution that worked, only the first time and not after, is the sample screenshot program in Qt, which I linked. As far as reproducibility, I am not sure, as this may be a peculiarity of my machine. Honestly, I am confused and am looking for direction or clarification to point me in the direction of a solution. I am a beginner to Qt.

The fact that it did work (even if only "once") is of interest. Did you try to compile the program and then run it outside of the IDE/dev environment? Does rebooting change anything (possibly running the program before anything else)? Also try to run the compiled program in a terminal and see if you get any output.

Yes. It is very strange. I've restarted and run the compiled program as the first thing done, with the same undesired screenshot result.. And it was never recompiled after the first compilation where it succeeded. So I am quite confused. I will sleep on it. Thanks for your direction

Thank you!! It is working when I compile it and run it directly from terminal (rather than from Qt Creator). This is very interesting!

I am guessing it's a permissions issue that's sidestepped when I call it directly from the terminal. I will investigate and report on the solution I hopefully find
